# Warning `LastBibItem' multiply defined'?

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, cross-referencing, warnings

What does this warning actually mean?

I wrote two different LaTeX files which I combined into a single LaTeX file. (first main document, first references, second main document, second references). As far as I can see there are no conflicting labels. The references were added by copying and pasting .bbl file into main .tex document.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805).

Comment: It is possible that a package you load automatically sets a `\label` called `LastBibitem` in the bibliography. If you have two bibliographies you end up with two such labels and the warning you quote. As far as I know this is not a standard feature of core LaTeX, so we can only help you properly if you can tell us more about the document that produces the warning. This is best done in a small example document that reproduces the issue with as little excess code as possible.